# Structure for storing string values in two-dimensional list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to create a matrix-like structure which can be accessed by its names of the columns and rows.

```
'''
           Misalign    CPU     Ret
LU_factor   0           6       21
Random      2           10      5
'''

row=["LU_factor","Random"]
col=['Misalign', 'CPU', 'Ret']
Total=[['0', '6', '21'],['2', '10', '5']]

for i in range(0,len(Total)):
    for j in range(0,len(Total[i])):
        print(Total[i][j],end=" ")
        # Matrix[row[i]][col[j]] =Total[i][j]

#print(Matrix)
```

I do not know what format or data structure I should use to store above data such that I could able to access like:

```
Matrix["LU_factor"]["CPU"] =6
Matrix["Random"]["Ret"] = 5
```

I have found one solution through `numpy structured array`, but I am looking for the solution without using numpy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dictionaries of dictionaries, something like:

```
M = {"LU_factor": {'Misalign': 0, 'CPU': 6, 'Ret': 21}, 'Random': {'Misalign': 2, 'CPU': 10, 'Ret': 5}}
```

should works, you can access or assign values respectively with `M["LU_factor"]["CPU"]` and `M["LU_factor"]["CPU"] = 5`.

Specifically you can build the structure you need with a dict comprehension, using your example:

```
row=["LU_factor","Random"]
col=['Misalign', 'CPU', 'Ret']
Total=[['0', '6', '21'],['2', '10', '5']]

M = {r:{c:Total[k][i] for i, c in enumerate(col)} for k, r in enumerate(row)}
```